# GPay Magento 2 Extension installation procedure

Tags: magento2, xampp, amazon

How do I install this? Please help me with procedure. I dont want to break my setup

I am confused with where should I put all those files. I am working on local XAMPP environment for learning purpose then I will upload it to EC2.

Comment: All the files for GPay extension installation will go in

app\code\UnboundCommerce\<zip files> folder OR
app\code\UnboundCommerce\GPay\<zip files> OR
app\code\UnboundCommerce\GPay\1.0.0\<zip files>

I am quite confused, please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create any folder under the app/code/.
Rather just unzip the Gpay extension under the app/code/ folder.
Your zip code should have the folder with vendorname called UnboundCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the much required help. This has been resolved.

app/code/UnboundCommerce/Google Pay/

Then you run setup upgrade, di compile and content deploy. Done